# DOMDocument and FBML/Google + Button not working

Tags: fbml, domdocument, google-plus-one

Well I'm having a bit of an issue, I have an application that uses DOMDocument to display some content but it is removing some code that is needed for FBML and a Google +1 button to display.

For example, Facebook's like button is `<fb:like>`, it is removing `fb:` from the string. Google's +1 button is like `<g:plusone>` and it's removing `g:`.

Is there any way to make it not remove that part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve both issues.

With Facebook like button, you will want to use the HTML5 version.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

ex: `<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

With Google's Plus one you can use the HTML5 version as well. See: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/

ex: `<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall" ... ></div>`